# Comparative Sentence Classification

Tags: classification, natural-language

I've been having a difficult time looking for a solution to identifying the comparative sentence. I like to extract the first noun (NP1) or second noun (NP2) from the given sentence fragment with comparaed word. First, I want to extract the comparative sentence, then I want to extract the entity(NP1).